# why the blur() can't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>test</title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
   $('#target').blur(function() {
 alert('welcome,boy.');
  })
</script>
   </head>

 <body>
  <form>
<input id="target" type="text" value="Field 1" />
 <input type="text" value="Field 2" />
  </form>
 <div id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

the jquery.js is in my js file, i put the above code in a file named test.html. when i click the first input textbox then click at other place. there is no popup an alert box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script runs immediately when the browser reads it in the HTML, which is before it even looks at the body. When the script runs, the `#target` element doesn't exist yet.

One solution would be to move the script to the bottom of `<body>`. Another would be to use jQuery's DOM ready function:

```
$(function() {
    $('#target').blur(function() {
        alert('welcome,boy.');
    });
});
```

In that case, you could still put the script at the head, and the script itself would run. However, it would put off running the part inside the `$(function () { /* code here */ } )` wrapper until the browser has read all of the HTML and has built its nice tree of DOM elements.

Comment: @mikeonrails: +1'd, anyway. A good answer is a good answer :)

Comment: Similar answer to @mikeonrails, but yours explains much more.

Answer (score 3):

It's because #target doesn't exist when that code executes. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('#target').blur(function() {
      alert('welcome,boy.');
    });
  });
</script>
```